# Docker: How to use "docker/compose" container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to run Docker Compose inside a Docker container using the official [docker/compose container](https://hub.docker.com/r/docker/compose).

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM docker/compose:latest
WORKDIR /
COPY ./docker-compose.yml .
COPY ./.env .
CMD [ "docker-compose", "up"]
```

Running `docker build -t my-container .` works. But running `docker run --privileged my-container` fails with:

```
> Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?
>
> If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to specify `DOCKER_HOST`, and if yes, to what?

Comment: Sorry I don't know what could be wrong with with, but I'm curious to know what could be the point of running docker-compose inside a docker container. That means you create containers inside containers ?

Comment: You can't run this without giving the container access to the host's Docker socket...at which point it's probably strictly easier to run `docker-compose` directly without launching a container to launch containers.

Comment: @Peterrabbit This is for a local test network. I have an application made up of 3 containers, and I want to run 4 independent instances of the application locally. To ensure encapsulation of the 4 instances I though it would be easiest to put each into a container.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the image docker/compose is used to in order to build docker-compose tool not to launch docker inside.
It's designed to be used by someone who would edit docker-compose source code.

However you could use the `dind` image (docker in docker).

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `docker-compose` within `dind` (docker-in-docker), like so:

```
FROM docker:20.10-dind
RUN apk add docker-compose
WORKDIR /
COPY ./docker-compose.yml .
COPY ./.env .
CMD [ "docker-compose", "up"]
```

Comment: This won't especially help.  A container only runs one thing; if it's running `docker-compose up` then it's not running a nested Docker daemon.

Answer (score 0):

Try `docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it container_name`

It will share docker socket.